# Trying to use fwrite to write a string in binary/hex in C

Tags: c, binary, fwrite

I'm trying to write a string out to a file in hexadecimal form.

For example, if I have the string:   "Hello"

I want it to be outputted to the file as:    4845 4C4C 4F.

I know the function to use is fwrite, but when I use fwrite, it writes the string as "Hello" instead of the binary representation.

I use the following function to try and convert it: fwrite(buffer, 1, 5, output), where buffer is the string "Hello", output is the destination file, 1 is the size of a character, and 5 is the number of times I want to write.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean you want the output to the file to be the ASCII string "48454C4C4F"?

Comment: Yes, the spaces were there for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to write each character in its hexadecimal form; you could use sprintf to make each such string to be printed.

Comment: Thank you. Would sprintf print the ASCII representation? I want the binary representation, and from what I understand, the ASCII representation is not the same as binary representation.

Comment: "Binary" = ones and zeros, which is NOT what you asked for.

Comment: Binary is the same as hexadecimal form when it's all said and done.

1010 = A = 1010

Comment: @user2662032 "hexadecimal" and "binary" are visual representations of a number. Internally, the letter 'H' is internally represented by a number, 52 (decimal) or 48 (hex) or 01001000 (binary). If you want to write out 'H', then you use `fwrite` to write the 'H' and the file will contain that number. If you want to "see" the number '48' (hex) or '52' (decimal) or '01001000' (binary) printed when you view it on the screen, then you must format them as ASCII digits using a formatting routine, such as `fprintf` or `sprintf`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `buffer` has your zero-terminated string, and `output` represents the `FILE` pointer you want to write to, then:

```
int i;

for ( i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++ )
    fprintf( output, "%02X", buffer[i] );
```

So you have to format each byte of the string as an ASCII value.

Your example showed the upper case character codes for "Hello", so you could convert to upper in the process if you wish:

```
for ( i = 0; i < strlen(buffer); i++ )
    fprintf( output, "%02X", toupper(buffer[i]) );
```

Comment: Hmm ok, so you're saying that fwrite is not the correct function in this case?

Comment: @user2662032 not if you need to have it also convert binary to ASCII as above (if I understood your problem statement correctly). `fprintf` does that formatting for you. You could use `fwrite` if you first convert your string's character codes to an ASCII sequence, then use `fwrite` but that would be much more verbose. `fwrite` writes exactly the data in the buffer. The data for "Hello" is the set of ASCII characters representing "Hello". The code I show is the set of ASCII characters converted from the binary representation of "Hello".